# Collisions in random functions

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, variance, means, collision-detection

Consider a random function, from $\{0, 1\}^n$ to $\{0, 1\}^n$.

For a particular string $y^{*} \in \{0, 1\}^n$ in the image of the function, in expectation over the randomness, how many strings in the domain map to $y^{*}$? Additionally, what is the variance of this distribution?

My intuition says that it should be only constantly many, at most, because a random function should not have too many collisions with high probability. But I do not know how to make this formal.

Comment: When you say "random function", do you mean that a function is chosen uniformly at random from the $(2^n)^{(2^n)}$ possible functions $\{0, 1\}^n \to \{0, 1\}^n$?  If so, I would have thought the distribution would be binomial with an obvious mean and an easily found variance

Comment: Yes, I meant a function chosen "uniformly at random" from all possible functions from $n$ bits to $n$ bits. Could you elaborate your intuition?

Answer (score 2):

- $y^*$ is one of the $2^n$ strings in $\{0, 1\}^n$
- any string $x$ is mapped to $y^*$ with probability $2^{-n}$ independently of the others
- so the total number mapped to $y^*$ has a binomial distribution $\text{Bin}(2^n,2^{-n})$
- which has mean $1$
- and variance $1-2^{-n}$
- and for large $n$ is close to a Poisson distribution with parameter $1$